# База учебных заведений стран СНГ

Tags: база-данных

Для одного проекта срочно требуется база всех учебных заведений стран СНГ (в первую очередь России). Желательно с адресами и телефонами.

Знаю, можно попробовать спарсить с различных сайтов, но может есть уже готовая база в удобном формате...

Буду рад:

1. Готовым базам
2. Сайтам с **наиболее** полным списком

**UP:**

[Справочник по вузам России](http://abitur.nica.ru/) (2906 штук)

Comment: Являюсь разработчиком сайта-каталога вузов России. Для каких целей нужна информация?
Сам проект находится в предбоевом состоянии, расположен [здесь](http://uniup.ru).

Comment: Являюсь разработчиком сайта-каталога вузов России. Для каких целей нужна информация?
Сам проект находится в предбоевом состоянии, расположен [здесь](http://uniup.ru).

Comment: Даа, по сравнению с Вашим справочником, у меня - пустая база)

Comment: Информация нужна для соц. сети (не классической, с упором на образование и развитие участников). Сейчас активно идет привлечение различных школ, центров и клубов в Москве (спортивных, интеллектуальных, творческих итд). Спасибо за ссылку, Проект интересный, но у вас пока тоже далеко не все ВУЗы..

Comment: Ну там основные, как я понял, забивал базу заказчик.  
У меня проект тоже что-то типа соц-сети, значит будем конкурентами? ;)

Comment: Думаю нет)) мы предоставляем немного другие услуги мне кажется) а вообще даже наверное в будущем сотрудничество в каких-то аспектах возможно

Comment: Все может быть :) Желаю успехов!